# Inverter constructed using LDMOS transistors

Tags: power, inverter

I have the following question: is it possible to construct an inverter using LDMOS transistors when HV power supply is equal to 30 V and maximum VGS for LDMOS transistors is 5 V? Moreover, lower MV domain is 5 V.

See the attachment for visualization - problem section.

I can do following solution - see the attachment (solution section). However, doing it means constant current consumption and problems to turn on PMOS (apply 25 V on its gate). PMOS is turned on through 5R resistor.

Do you know if it is possible to construct such an inverter?

**EDIT: IT MUST BE AN INTEGRATED CIRCUIT SOLUTION.**

[image: LDMOS inverter - problem and possible bad(?) solution]

Comment: the search term you are looking for is "high side driver"

Comment: I took a fast look into Google, but at the moment I must leave the computer. I'll investigate your term as fast as I can. However one important remark: this should be **integrated circuit (IC) solution**.

Comment: @ Brian Drummond - I cannot find anything reasonable for **"high side drive"** term. I'm leaving it as my solution with additional switch works fine and I do not have any better idea. I'll add it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the schematic to this questions as I promised:

[image]

I worried about the current flowing in the resistor divider, but it is not as bad as I thought. 500 uA for 100 kHz output signal works perfectly. Input capacitance of transistors is on the level of few fF. Very big transistors can achieve the input capacitance equal to single pF, but the chosen current of the voltage divider can turn on/off the PMOS relatively fast.

The only remark I have is the fact that, when output goes low, there can be **undershoot** on the gate of PMOS and its gate-source voltage can go lower than 25 V. It can be solved simply by driving output PMOS and NMOS transistors using no **overlaping** clock.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a level translator circuit.

The core of this picture is what you will looking for.  There is no quiescent current.

[image]

This picture is snipped from EE-Times article [here](http://www.eetimes.com/document.asp?doc_id=1231111) as it gives some good background.

I've implemented similar circuits lots of times.  It can be used to also shift the negative rail too, but the circuit is flipped and the transistors inverted (PMOS for NMOS etc.).  The catch is that you can only shift one rail at a time, i.e. first the bottom rail and then the top rail.  Having an output inverter is useful as this circuit is sensitive to loading on the internal nodes of T5 and T7.

You need to recognize the key aspect of the circuit can be reduced to the following:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffFWj9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: It is not a solution to my problem. It is a normal level shifter / level converter from VCCA to VCCB. What I need is a level converter from 0-5 V to 25-30 V.

Comment: This is what is usually used as an IC solution.  I've used similar designs in about 4 - 5 chips. For your problem you would first go from 0 - 5 V to 0 - 30 V and then have a second stage that goes to 25 - 30 V.

Comment: I know that this is usually used as level shifter / level converter IC solution, but it is not what I need. Moreover, I cannot go from 0-5 V domain to 0-30 V due to the fact that I do not have transistors for 30 V domain. I only have LDMOS transistors for VDS = 30 V and VGS = 5 V. That's the problem.

Comment: @Tako With this circuit you can go from any voltage to any other voltage , but you need to use only the LDMOS.  The circuit above is for a generic case and points out the fundamentals, you should be able to use variations to implement exactly what you need. In your case you probably need to replace the T8/T9 inverter with a simple NMOS like T6. The key is the cross -coupled PMOS.  I don't have access right now, but later I will post some schematics from working Si.  I'll throw in a brief circuit right now.

Comment: I appreciate your discussion and your help :), but what you propose is a standard level shifter / level converter. Please be aware that in my case, you have only 5 V and 30 V as power supplies and NMOS/PMOS transistors from 5 V domain and LDMOS transistors that can have VGS = 5 V and VDS = 30 V. You do not have power supply equal to 25 V to go from 5 V to 25 V using level converter / level shifter. Is that clear?